# Cannot update the parent component state from inside a Modal (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to write the value of a TextInput. When I press the TextInput, it brings a Modal, which contains a FlatList of some Touchable options and when an option is pressed, it needs to update the state of the parent and TextInput value must be changed accordingly. (ex: User presses the empty TextInput, a Modal with the options 1, 2, and 3, user picks 2, modal closes and TextInput shows 2) It does not change the state but with console.log statements, I can see there is nothing wrong with the data.

This is my parent component, it is the TextInput that needs to be changed:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { TextInput } from "react-native-paper";
import BPSelectionModal from "./BPSelectionModal";

type Props = {
  capitalize: "none" | "sentences" | "words" | "characters" | undefined;
  label: string;
  length: number | undefined;
  style: object | undefined;
  onChangeText(e: any): void | undefined;
  inputValue: string | undefined;
  isSelectable: boolean | undefined;
  isPressed?: (x: boolean) => void; //"?" marks that the prop is optional/nullable.
  country?: string;
  dataURL?: string;
  setDataURL?: (x: string | undefined) => void;
  postKey?: (a: string) => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  keyboard?: any;
  isDate?: boolean;
  setModalOpened?: (x: boolean) => void;
  isModalOpened?: boolean;
  setTitle?: (x: string) => void;
};

const BPCreateInput = (props: Props) => {
  const [isModalOpened, setModalOpened] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<string>();

  return (
    <View  style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: "100%", alignContent: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          props.isSelectable
            ? (props.setDataURL?.(props.dataURL),
              props.setModalOpened?.(true),
              props.isPressed?.(true),
              props.setTitle?.(props.label),
              console.log("isPressed: ", props.isModalOpened))
            : null
        }
        style={{ zIndex: 10, marginHorizontal: 8, width: "100%" }}
      >
        <TextInput
          pointerEvents={props.isSelectable ? "none" : "auto"}
          autoCapitalize={props.capitalize}
          label={props.label}
          mode="outlined"
          maxLength={props.length}
          activeOutlineColor="#0C7ECF"
          style={props.style}
          onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
          value={selectedItem}
          disabled={props.disabled}
          keyboardType={props.keyboard}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {isModalOpened ? (
      
      <BPSelectionModal
        isOpened={isModalOpened}
        setOpened={(x) => setModalOpened(x)}
        dataURL={props.dataURL}
        title={props.label}
        setSelectedText={(a) => (setSelectedItem(a), console.log("a: ", a))}
        postKey={(a) => props.postKey?.(a) }
        country={props.country}
        isDate={props.isDate}
      /> 
    ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

export default BPCreateInput;
```

And this is the Modal component which contains the options:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Platform,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

import { REACT_APP_IOS_URL_API, ANDROID_URL_API } from "@env";
let baseURL =
  Platform.OS === "android" ? ANDROID_URL_API : REACT_APP_IOS_URL_API;

import Modal from "react-native-modal";

type Props = {
  isOpened: boolean | undefined;
  setOpened: (x: boolean) => void;
  dataURL: string | undefined;
  setSelectedText: (x: string) => void;
  title: string | undefined;
  postKey: (x: string) => void;
  country?: string;
  isDate?: boolean;
};

interface DataItem {
  key: string;
  text: string;
}

const BPSelectionModal = (props: Props) => {

  const data = Array.from({ length: 1 }, (_, i) => `dummy${i + 1}`); //dummy data

  return (
    <Modal
      isVisible={props.isOpened}
      style={data.length > 3 ? styles.modalStyleLong : styles.modalStyleShort}
      onBackdropPress={() => props.setOpened(false)}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 0 ,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 22,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{selectedItem}</Text>
            <FlatList
              data={data}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={styles.btnStyle}
                  onPress={() => {
                    console.log("item: ", item);
                    props.setSelectedText(item);
                    props.setOpened(false);
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{item}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
            />
        </View>
      </Modal>
  );
};

export default BPSelectionModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove isModalOpened condition

```js
// {isModalOpened ? (
      <BPSelectionModal
        isOpened={isModalOpened}
        setOpened={(x) => setModalOpened(x)}
        dataURL={props.dataURL}
        title={props.label}
        setSelectedText={(a) => (setSelectedItem(a), console.log("a: ", a))}
        postKey={(a) => props.postKey?.(a) }
        country={props.country}
        isDate={props.isDate}
      /> 
//    ) : null}
```